# OpenCV populating CvMat with data and verifying it

Tags: pointers, opencv

I have a vector of TrainingSets(struct below) called data

```
class TrainingSet
{
public:
int time;
float input[2];
float output[3*NUM_TRACKING_POINTS];

TrainingSet(int t, float in[2], float out[3*NUM_TRACKING_POINTS])
{
    time = t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        input[i] = in[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3*NUM_TRACKING_POINTS; i++)
        output[i] = out[i];
}
TrainingSet()
{

}
};
```

And then I try to take the contents of this Vector, and put them into CvMats for the purpose of training a Neural Network.

```
int datasize = data.size();
float** in = new float*[datasize];
float** out = new float*[datasize];

for (int i = 0; i < datasize; i++) {
    in[i] = new float[2*TIME_STEPS];
    out[i] = new float[3*NUM_TRACKING_POINTS];
}

for ( int i = 0 ; i < datasize; i ++)
{
    // get the first set in the sequence.
    TrainingSet tset = data.front();
    data.pop();

    // get the inputs
    in[i] = new float[2*TIME_STEPS];
    in[i][0] = tset.input[0];
    in[i][1] = tset.input[1];

    // get the outputs
    out[i] = new float[3*NUM_TRACKING_POINTS];
    for (int j = 0; j < 3*NUM_TRACKING_POINTS; j++)
        out[i][j] = tset.output[j];

    for (int j = 2; j < 2*TIME_STEPS; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            in[i][j] = 0.0f;
        else
            in[i][j] = in[i - 1][j - 2];
    }
}

// make matrices from data.
CvMat *trainInput = cvCreateMat(datasize, 2*TIME_STEPS, CV_32FC1);
cvInitMatHeader(trainInput, datasize, 2*TIME_STEPS, CV_32FC1, in);
CvMat *trainOutput = cvCreateMat(datasize, 3*NUM_TRACKING_POINTS, CV_32FC1);
cvInitMatHeader(trainOutput, datasize, 3*NUM_TRACKING_POINTS, CV_32FC1, out);

for (int x = 0; x < datasize; x++)
{
    cout << "IN: ";
    for (int y = 0; y < 2*TIME_STEPS; y++)
        cout << cvmGet(trainInput, x, y) << " ";
    cout << endl << "IN: ";
    for (int y = 0; y < 2*TIME_STEPS; y++)
        cout << in[x][y] << " ";
    cout << endl << "OUT: ";
    for (int y = 0; y < 3 * NUM_TRACKING_POINTS; y++)
        cout << cvmGet(trainOutput, x, y) << " ";
    cout << endl << "OUT: ";
    for (int y = 0; y < 3 * NUM_TRACKING_POINTS; y++)
        cout << out[x][y] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

That last forloop is to check to see if the matrices contents are the data I just fed it, but they don't match. The Matrices seem to have completely different data.

Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that `in` and `out` are not a *contiguous* array, but an array of pointers.

I think the cvMat needs a contiguous memory array to be able to operate on it.

Also once you create the array, you don't need to create a CvMat from it, just
use the

```
CvSetData( header, data ).
```

Comment: First I should state I do not use C++ very often, I'm not very good. That said, I don't know how to make a contiguous array for this data. As the length of the data file in training sets is variable, and so is the data in the training sets. Also the neural network's train() function wants matrices for input and output sets to train with, can you give me an example of using CvSetData() to train a neural network?

Comment: I found that I could instantiate my matrices with just:
 CvMat trainInput = cvMat(datasize,2*TIME_STEPS,CV_32S, in);
 CvMat trainOutput = cvMat(datasize, 3*NUM_TRACKING_POINTS, CV_32FC1, out);

But this causes a weird problem where it just fails to run the program at all. It compiles, but when I run it it gives me an exception before it even gets to my program, somewhere in the kernel.